# Initial values in useState not updated after re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Pretty sure I'm missing something fundamental about React.

So here's the code:

```
export function EditTagsModal({existingTags}) {
  console.log('existingTags', existingTags);

  const [selectedTags, setSelectedTags] = React.useState(existingTags);

  console.log('selectedTags:', selectedTags);
  ...
}
```

In a parent component, `<EditTagsModal />` is consumed like this:

```
{tags && <EditTagsModal existingTags={tags} /> }
```

Here is how it goes down:

1. `existingTags` starts with, say, `['hello']`
2. `setSelectedTags` is doing its thing.
3. `selectedTags` is now `['hello', 'world', 'world']`.
4. Then I send tags to server, close modal, parent re-render.
5. Now the `tags` returned by server is `['hello', 'world']`, without the duplicates.
6. Here's the thing: Now I open the modal again, I'm still seeing my values in `selectedTags`(in that second console.log above) that has the duplicates, not the `tags`(the first console.log) from my server.

What's up with react?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `selectedTags` state in the `useState` hook is only initialized once.

If `tags` remains a truthy defined array (*even empty arrays are truthy and defined*) then the `EditTagsModal` component remains mounted by `{tags && <EditTagsModal existingTags={tags} />}`. If the `tags` value, and thus the `existingTags` prop updates and `EditTagsModal` is rerendered, then you should implement an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `existingTags` prop to update the local state when the prop value updates.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setSelectedTags(existingTags);
}, [existingTags]);
```

`useEffect` with a dependency array is synonymous to a class component's `componentDidMount` ***and*** `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle methods.

Comment: yea I have actually tried that. no dice. i guess my problem lies somewhere else. but im gonna accept this answer since it sounds definitive for the issue i laid out in general. thanks!

Comment: @kyw Sure thing. If you happen to post a new question regarding any deeper dive into the issue, feel free to ping me here with a link to it and I can take a look.